# How the "p" array store the values in the following code using C++ std::normal_distribution?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, std, normal-distribution

I'm trying to add Gaussian noise to the elements of a vector and therefore I would like to use the std::normal_distribution template in my code. I was looking  at an example at this link:[Normal distribution example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/), but I can't figure out how int `p[10]={}` is being write, I have run the code and seems to be working fine.

Here is the code snippet that I can't figure out, `p` seems to be storing the values in this for loop:

```
 int p[10]={};

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    double number = distribution(generator);
    if ((number>=0.0)&&(number<10.0)) ++p[int(number)];
  }
```

Here is the complete code as reference:

```
// normal_distribution
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  const int nrolls=10000;  // number of experiments
  const int nstars=100;    // maximum number of stars to distribute

  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0,2.0);

  int p[10]={};

  for (int i=0; i<nrolls; ++i) {
    double number = distribution(generator);
    if ((number>=0.0)&&(number<10.0)) ++p[int(number)];
  }

  std::cout << "normal_distribution (5.0,2.0):" << std::endl;

  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << "-" << (i+1) << ": ";
    std::cout << std::string(p[i]*nstars/nrolls,'*') << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And the expected result (which it's the same output I have after running this code):

```
normal_distribution (5.0,2.0):
0-1: *
1-2: ****
2-3: *********
3-4: ***************
4-5: ******************
5-6: *******************
6-7: ***************
7-8: ********
8-9: ****
9-10: *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int p[10]={};` declares an array of 10 `int` elements that are all initialized to `0`.

`++p[int(number)];` increments an array element for a generated `number` that is between 0..9, inclusive.

The `operator[]` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the prefix `operator++`, so `p[number]` is evaluated first to get a reference to an `int` in the array, and then `++` increments that `int`.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your reply. It's clear for me now, I read carefully the code after your explanation and makes sense now, I increment by one some element of the array when the random number "picks" one of the array indexes.